# Member variable in template?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to pass a member variable into a template. In example, if I have the following:

`struct MyStruct
{
    MyType MyMember;
}`

How can I do something like:

`MyType MyVar = MyTemplate<MyStruct, &MyStruct::MyMember, MyType>();`

I tried to search around and didn't find anything that explain exactly how to achieve that... Sorry if that is a stupid question, I'm pretty new to c++...

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Pretty advance for someone _pretty new to C++_...

Comment: ummm, I don't think you can take an address of a data member of some class. This doesn't make sense to me. What should the value be? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Fiktik: Yes you can, those are _member-object_ and _member-function pointers_

Comment: @K-ballo I understand pointer-to-method, but I don't think I've seen pointer-to-member-object ... seems like I have some studying to do :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here goes something:

```
template< typename Class, typename MemberType, MemberType Class::*Member >
struct my_template;
```

and you can use it like this:

```
my_template< MyStruct, MyType, &MyStruct::MyMember > _;
```

Comment: AH! I had to put the member at the end as I needed the type of it! Seems logical now, thanks a lot!